# Running python script concurrently based on trigger

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, concurrency

What would be best way to solve following problem with Python ?

I have real-time data stream coming to my object-oriented storage from user application (json files being stored into S3 storage in Amazon).

Upon receiving of each JSON file, I have to within certain time (1s in this instance) process data in the file and generate response that is send back to the user. This data is being processed by simple Python script.

My issue is, that the real-time data stream can at the same time generate even few hundreds JSON files from user applications that I need to run trough my Python script and I don't know how to approach this the best way.

I understand, that way to tackle this would be to use trigger based Lambdas that would execute job on the top of every file once uploaded from real-time stream in server-less environment, however this option is quite expensive compared to have single server instance running and somehow triggering jobs inside.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless can actually be cheaper than using a server. It is *much* cheaper when there are periods of no activity because you don't need to pay for a server doing nothing.

The hardest part of your requirement is **sending the response back to the user**. If an object is uploaded to S3, there is no easy way to send back a response and it isn't even obvious who is the user that sent the file.

You could process the incoming file and then **store a response back in a similarly-named object**, and the client could then poll S3 for the response. That requires the upload to use a unique name that is somehow generated.

An alternative would be for the data to be sent to **AWS API Gateway**, which can trigger an AWS Lambda function and then *directly return* the response to the requester. No server required, automatic scaling.

If you wanted to use a **server**, then you'd need a way for the client to send a message to the server with a reference to the JSON object in S3 (or with the data itself). The server would need to be running a web server that can receive the request, perform the work and provide back the response.

**Bottom line:** Think about the data flow first, rather than the processing.